# Azure Api Manager configure multiple service fabric endpoints to backend

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-api-management

In Azure API Manager how to I configure multiple service fabric clusters backend. Through the tutorial I was able to create the API Manager and configure one service fabric endpoint through the ARM template.

Can one instance of API Manager support multiple service fabric endpoints?

If so how do I configure to add another service fabric endpoint to the backend?

Is it possible to do it through portal?

Answer (score 0):

Portal does not have UI for that yet. But it's possible through API and ARM templates. Refer to backend entity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/backend/createorupdate. It's the same as with a single SF backend. You create new backend entity to hold connection information and credentials for your SF cluster. And use it's ID in set-backend-service policy to target call to it.

Comment: Does the second service fabric cluster have to be in the same VNet as the api managment?

Comment: Yes, it has to be accessible by APIM.